# How to set limit on folder memory running in Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker

I am running a script in `docker` container which create some files and logs information in that.
Command is

```
docker run -t --name a6f97966d3a2552283df -v  "/temp/a6f97966d3a2552283df":/usercode ubuntu_16_04:firsttry /usercode/script.sh
```

I want to limit the size of that folder which i have mounted using this command because log size may increase very much.
One solution for that may be i mount a virtual `filesystem` in container using following commands

```
mkdir -p /quota
mkdir -p /var/virtual_disks
touch /var/virtual_disks/directory_with_size_limit.ext3
dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/virtual_disks/directory_with_size_limit.ext3 count=51200
mkfs.ext3 /var/virtual_disks/directory_with_size_limit.ext3
mount -o loop,rw,usrquota,grpquota /var/virtual_disks/directory_with_size_limit.ext3 /quota
```

Its working fine on my local system but not in container.
Is there any other way of acheiving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now working fine.Actually the mounted path in folder should be the same as the `mount` path of the virtual `filesystem`

So the modified command is

`docker run -t --name a6f97966d3a2552283df -v  "/quota":/usercode ubuntu_16_04:firsttry /usercode/script.sh`